# How to deal with Google Tag Manage error?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I implemented this code below after the opening `<body>` tag. But I receive error message `Server error 500` or a blank page.

Why do I receive that result?

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxx"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer - it certainly is not caused by GTM. Server Error 500 sounds more like this is caused by your own server - maybe you have pasted the code into a PHP-block (or code of any other scripting language) that chokes on the JS code.

Comment: Know an old question but just noticed this happening myself. For me this was due to an adblocker blocking those scripts. Turning AdGuard off allowed them to fire fine.